# Oracle Remove Consecutive duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, gaps-and-islands

I have table in which I store the evauation results of customer. Evaluation  can be triggered multiple times. Below is the sample data

```
CUSTOMER_EVAL_RESULTS:
    SEQ    CUSTOMER_ID   STATUS   RESULT
    1       100           C        XYZ
    3       100           C        XYZ
    7       100           C        ABC
    8       100           C        PQR
    11      100           C        ABC
    12      100           C        ABC
```

From above data set I want only the rows with SEQ as 1,7,8,11.
I used below query suggested on other links but it is not giving the desired result. Please help

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT E.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID, STATUS, RESULT ORDER BY SEQ) ROW_NUM 
FROM CUSTOMER_EVAL_RESULTS E WHERE E.CUSTOMER_ID=100
) WHERE ROW_NUM=1;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can utilize LAG to check the previous row's value:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
 (
   SELECT E.*,
      LAG(RESULT)
      OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID, STATUS
           ORDER BY SEQ) prevResult 
   FROM CUSTOMER_EVAL_RESULTS E 
   WHERE E.CUSTOMER_ID=100
) 
WHERE prevResult IS NULL
   OR prevResult <> RESULT
```

Comment: Thanks:). I tried this one however giving me the same results. I want to remove only consecutive duplicates rows

Comment: @Ashish: It's not the same result as the ROW_NUMBER, this will return a row when the current `result` is different from the previous (or it's the 1st row). If you want to get a row when result or status changes you can remove the status from order by and add another LAG for the status.

Comment: I think I got your idea here. If I do not use the PARTITION inside OVER then it works. Thanks :)

Comment: @Ashish: You must at least `partition by customer_id`

Comment: @Ashish why not accept this as the correct answer.This exactly solves the problem mentioned in the question.

Comment: @dnoeth I just had a very similar problem and I agree with Ashish, removing the `PARTITION BY` is necessary. This works for me also.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889: Removing PARTITION BY might return a correct result in your case, but it's definitely neccessary if you process more than single CUSTOMER_ID

Comment: @dnoeth Including the `PARTITION BY` seemed to be performing some grouping of the in ways that wasn't desirable for removing consecutive duplicates. (Using `PARTITION BY`, duplicates were removed, whether or not they were consecutive.)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below

```
  select * from CUSTOMER_EVAL_RESULTS
  where not exists (select 1 from CUSTOMER_EVAL_RESULTS 
                    a,CUSTOMER_EVAL_RESULTS b
                    where a.seq_no < b.seq_no and a.customer_id=b.customer_id
                    and a.status=b.status and a.result=b.result     
                    and not exists(select 1 from CUSTOMER_EVAL_RESULTS c
                    where a.seq_no < c.seq_no and  c.seq_no < b.seq_no ));
```

Comment: Thanks:). There is one problem. SEQ_NO can have gaps. It is not always incremented by 1. I will modify the question example